# Netlogo : Slider ratio driving > Ifelse one-of random outcome

Tags: netlogo

I'm a little stuck, and wondering if it's a netlogo expectation - or something I'm doing wrong ?

I'm trying to set a choice, based on a slider ratio (called "determinate-ratio") - which then drives an Ifelse outcome, that sets a state.

Ideally - if i put the slider to 80% (of 100%).  I'd like to see the sum of the TRUE variable
[ "1-year-parabola" "5-year-parabola" "10-year-parabola"] ~ 80%

But instead I get a large variance - ie, sometimes I get 75, 90, 85 etc - instead of 80%

Is this something to expect, with the one-of construct (or way i'm doing it) ?

Or, can this be done better ?  (note: the population is a variable (slider input))

thank you :)

code below :

```
ifelse random 100 < determinate-ratio
[ set state one-of [ "1-year-parabola" "5-year-parabola" "10-year-parabola"]]
[ set state one-of [ "decline" "experimenting"]]
```

Comment: your code looks fine. This is a random process of course. How many agents are there? If there's not many, you would expect substantial variation.

Comment: @JenB great to hear from you :)  In this instance, only 100 agents

Comment: try it with 1000 agents and see what proportions you get

Comment: @JenB good idea, 1000 : max var 5%.  typically ~ 2%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say over how many runs you are seeing this variation, but it doesn't seem particularly wrong to me. Variation is an expected outcome of random processes, which is why ABMs must be run multiple times to get any sense of 'typical' behaviour.

Effectively you are drawing from a binomial distribution with probability of success of 0.8 and 100 trials. If you are not comfortable with the mathematics, then you can use an online binomial distribution calculator (such as the one by Stat Trek at https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) to get a feel for reasonable variation. For example, exactly 75 would occur in 4.4% of your model runs, and 8.7% would have 75 or fewer.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up ! :)  That was my next step to do an analysis of the outcomes to see the trend, though I wasn't sure if I'd missed a potential bias in the way I'd generated the randomness.